# MIPS ascii substring memory overwrite

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips

I'am using MARS MIPS simulator and There is a specific task to change a substring with another in a main Ascii string on the memory. However, simulator puts these 3 next to each other on the memory. When I shift characters of the main string to the right(if the second substring is longer than the first), it practically overwrites those of the substrings. Can I please hear some ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Tag as homework if it's homework.

Answer (score 0):

Add some empty space between them. ;)

```
str1:         .asciiz      "I'm string one"
some_space:   .space       40
str2:         .asciiz      "I'm the second string"
other_space:  .space       40
str3:         .asciiz      "I'm the last string"
guess_what:   .space       40
```

If you can't do this, declare three destination buffers (always with the `.space` above) where you copy your strings, then edit them directly there.

**EDIT**
You can keep these substrings in two buffers so when modifying the 'main' string you will still overwrite the substrings, but you don't need to bother because you've got their copy somewhere else. In practice, once you have your own copy of the substrings you can happily forget the original ones and overwrite them (if needed), using as reference the copies you got.
Probably this is all you can do. If you haven't got enough room is impossible to invent some other. You *have to* overwrite something. BTW after you modified the 'main' string you can put your copies after that, so the caller still finds the substrings.

Comment: Actually I was writing a subroutine that is to be called from some main caller, it was not my job to deal with that problem. I need to be sure that no overwrites occur. Thank you for your answer,I greatly appreciate that. But can you be a little more specific about those buffers please